# VB.net 2010 Execute Code line for line(Sendkeys, Wait/Sleep, Me, Close)

Tags: vb.net, sendkeys

I am struggling with a very simple line of code and it seems that VB.net does not execute it correctly.

Very simple example:

---

```
SendKeys.Send("Test")
Sendkeys.Send("Test2")
Sendkeys.Send{"{ENTER}")
Me.Close()
```

---

When I start the programm, it does not write Test and Test 2, it immediately  closes the program!

Even after adding this:

---

```
SendKeys.Send("Test")
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
Sendkeys.Send("Test2")
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
Sendkeys.Send{"{ENTER}")
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
Me.Close()
```

---

This also does not work! It does wait at the beginning without applying SENDKEYS!

### What DOES work is this:

```
SendKeys.Send("Test")
Sendkeys.Send("Test2")
Sendkeys.Send{"{ENTER}")
```

---

Whenever I don't use the wait/Sleep function or the me.close function, vb.net executes the sendkeys very well!

QUESTION: How can I add a sleep/wait function which waits PERFECTLY and continues LINE FOR LINE?

Comment: Where are you sending the keys to? Another application, or within your application?  If it is in your application, your problem might be that you are closing the application before it has the opportunity to read the message from the send keys.  Also, in what method in your form is this running?